# Debian linux not working after installation

Tags: debian, kernel, nvidia

I just installed Debian linux on my windows 10 computer thru rufus on an USB stick. After finishing the installation (With GRUB installed and linux not recognizing my windows installation) I restarted my computer and tried to boot. After booting my computer shows this error message:  (Linux-server is my computers network name)

> Debian GNU/Linux 10 Linux-server tty1
>
> Linux-server login: [     4.108321] noveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed
> to create kernel channel, -22

GRUB apears to start normally after turning on my computer but Windows does not appear

**I do not care about the files on windows or linux and just want to get Linux running**

Also the machine has a Intel i7 processor and a Nvidia grafics card, it was running windows 10 when linux was installed and the installation was perfect with just 2 things that I thought ware out of place.

1. The installation wizard was **not** able to setup the internet (My comuter uses wifi but it is not built in AND was beeing used thru an asus wifi stick (My computer has an Ethernet port but I do not use it)
2. Windows 10 was not detected when the GRUB installation message popped up (I think that is why windows is not bootable)

Sorry for my English and any responces will be Hightly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It sounds like your wifi device may require proprietary drivers.  Figure out which wifi driver is useful to your card.  For example, `firmware-iwlwifi` is for Intel wireless cards.  Once, you've found it, it's probably in `non-free`.  Here are two options:

- Use the [unofficial non-free debian installer](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/), or
- Use ethernet for installation, then append `non-free contrib` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, right after `main`.  Run `apt update` and then `apt install firmware-iwlwifi` (or what the package is for your device).  Then you can unplug the ethernet and continue with wifi.

2. `grub` uses the `os-prober` extension to find other installations.  Ensure that's installed with `apt install os-prober`, then `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Finally regarding this message:

> noveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to create kernel channel,

If you don't mind more proprietary drivers, installing `nvidia-driver` usually works pretty well when you have an nvidia card.  If you have an older card, then consider `nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver` or `nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver`.  See `apt show <package>` for a list of which cards are supported by each driver.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly.